# Woocommerce: Emails defer does not schedule action into action scheduler

Tags: php, email, woocommerce, action-scheduler

I've implemented code in my WooCommerce store to defer emails, based on a tutorial I found. I've customized the code, removing unnecessary parts, with the goal of enhancing the checkout loading process after an order is submitted.

However, I've encountered an issue: the action doesn't get sent to the action scheduler when the order status changes from pending to processing.

Here are some details about my server setup: WP CRON is turned off, but we invoke it from the webserver to run every 2 minutes. I've also experimented with turning WP CRON back on, but the problem persists.

Interestingly, there's a peculiar behavior where, sporadically, every 15-20 minutes, the action scheduler event gets scheduled, and emails are sent.

I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure the action is scheduled every time the status changes from pending to processing and how to seamlessly integrate it into the action scheduler. Perhaps someone can identify where I may be going wrong.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Code bellow:

```
class DeferSendingWooCommerceEmails {
private static $instance;
private $default_defer_time;
// An associative array to match $email_id with email class, to allow for the deferring of different emails.
private $email_id_to_defer;

// Returns an instance of this class. 
public static function get_instance() {
    if ( null == self::$instance ) {
        self::$instance = new DeferSendingWooCommerceEmails();
    } 
    return self::$instance;
}
// Initialize the plugin variables.
public function __construct() {
    $this->default_defer_time = 30;
    $this->email_id_to_defer = array(
        'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing' => $this->default_defer_time,
);

    $this->init();
}


// Set up WordPress specfic actions.
public function init() {
    // Set all WooCommerce emails to be deferred.
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_defer_transactional_emails', '__return_true' );

    // Allow most emails to be sent as normal but prevent emails listed in $this->email_id_to_defer. Schedule them for a time in the future.
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_allow_send_queued_transactional_email', array( $this, 'whether_send_queued_wc_email' ), 10, 3 );

    // This is the scheduled function that will send the email.
    add_action( 'send_deferred_woocommerce_email', array( $this, 'send_deferred_woocommerce_email' ), 10, 2 );

}

private function get_email_defer_time( $filter ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( $filter, $this->email_id_to_defer ) ) {
        return $this->email_id_to_defer[ $filter ];
    }

    return $this->default_defer_time;
}


public function whether_send_queued_wc_email( $true, $filter, $args ) {
    
    if ( array_key_exists( $filter, $this->email_id_to_defer ) ) {
        $event_id = as_schedule_single_action( time() + $this->get_email_defer_time( $filter ), 'send_deferred_woocommerce_email', array( $filter, $args ) );
        return false;
    }
    return $true;
}


// Send the deferred email for order $order_id.
public function send_deferred_woocommerce_email( $filter, $args = array() ) {
    //error_log( 'send_deferred_woocommerce_email for order: ' . $order_id );

    // Use same code as WC_Emails::send_queued_transactional_email() in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php
    WC_Emails::instance();
    // Ensure gateways are loaded in case they need to insert data into the emails.
    WC()->payment_gateways();
    WC()->shipping();

    do_action_ref_array( $filter . '_notification', $args );
    }
    }

    $DeferSendingWooCommerceEmails = new DeferSendingWooCommerceEmails();
```